# Is a function that makes local use of mutability pure?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, mutation, imperative

I'm a beginner to Scala, FP, and programming in general. I'm trying to understand when something can be called proper FP.

If we say that functional programming is about chaining functions together so that f(x) = x (for one input and one output), can you say you're still doing fp if you build functions that rely on local mutation, but which always have the same output for the same input?

Compare the following Scala code, which is meant to always produce 10 for x <= 10, and x for all x > 10. That is to say, the function always has a predictable result, unless my logic in constructing them was flawed:

```scala
def imp(x: Int): Int = {
  var y = x // in case x is an immutable value
  while (y < 10) {
    y += 1
  }
  return y
}

def tailRec(x: Int): Int = {
  if (x >= 10) return x
  else tailRec(x + 1)
}

val x = 2;
imp(x); //10
tailRec(x); //10
```

I would say that my imperative function has no side effects (it does not alter state outside of the function). I would say that it locally breaks referential transparency, as y is not just a name for a value, but changes over time. However, if we think about the imperative function from a global setting, it does not seem to matter, as the function always gives the same result as the proper pure tailrecursive function. So is this still FP, if you consider the function as a black box and only focus on f(x)=x?

Comment: I say `imp()` is definitely pure. If you check out the definition of pure functions e.g. in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), you will see that mutation of *local* variables has no impact on purity. Languages usually recognize that sometimes mutability is necessary. E.g. Clojure supports [mutable state](https://clojure.org/reference/transients), and everything is ok as long as the mutable data do not escape local scope.

Comment: Yeah the function is RT from outside, but breaks RT in the inside. That is fine, but there are other reasons to avoid it, like consistency. If the question is if you can mix these kind of functions with a functional codebase then the answer is yes. But, usually there has to be a good reason to resort to this kind of code, but such reasons depend on the team.

Comment: BTW, bit off topic, but don't use `return` is dangerous and rarely ever actually needed.

Comment: Hi Luis and Nikos, thanks for your comments. Luis: First, about the return statement, that's interesting. I have found a discussion on it here: https://users.scala-lang.org/t/dont-use-return-in-scala/3688. Secondly, with consistency problems, you mean that your code now has an inconsistent style and becomes hard to read?

Comment: Yeah exactly that. If you open a code base and is a mix of immutable functions and imperative functions one may wonder what is the rationale and what style one should use for new features.

Comment: You're over-thinking this. All of these things are abstractions built over real physical memory and circuitry. At some level *no* function is pure because memory is getting allocated on the heap, values are being moved in and out of registers, etc. Even if you disregard that, scala runs on the JVM which is not pure. The question you need to be asking yourself is "does this function always return the same value for the same input?". If so then it's pure enough. Unless we're talking in the context of some sort of timing attack, why would you ever care about the *internal* purity of a subroutine?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Jared, well I care most practically because I find writing small chunks of imperative code in small functions very natural. I imagine you end up writing a sort of stack-oriented C-like style if you write an entire program this way.  And I'm not sure that will pass on a job interview for a Scala job... Secondly, left to my own devices I would probably produce some sort of imperative/FP Frankenstein code, and I wanted to know if I should be more disciplined

Comment: @Alp that's a much more reasonable line of questioning than what came across in the question. I would say that in general you want to use purity even internally unless it makes the code more complicated or too slow as shown by the profiler. As for what to do in an interview, I've never interviewed for a Scala job so I can't say, although I'd be surprised if the Scala consensus deviates much from my generalized take. It also likely depends on whether you're writing a *service* or a *library*. I usually prioritize performance more for the latter, but YMMV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those functions are definitely pure by definition. I'll use the one provided by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), which says that a pure function has the following properties:

> 1. the function return values are identical for identical arguments (no variation with local static variables, non-local variables, mutable reference arguments or input streams, i.e., referential transparency), and
> 2. the function has no side effects (no mutation of local static variables, non-local variables, mutable reference arguments or input/output streams).

The only case in which the internal state of a function was relevant would be if said state was *static*, outliving each individual function call and possibly influencing the return value in subsequent calls (something that in Scala should only happen if a method mutates the state of its class).

With regard to mixing together pure and impure code, it's definitely difficult to do so well, but with some understanding I think it's feasible. I would say that the best way to do so is exemplified by the Scala Collection API itself, as you can see for example in the definition of the [`List.map`](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/a095115b43398feeac3ee4329edb87f87da00012/scala2-library-cc/src/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L245-L259) method: expose a pure API and use local mutable state in a small, constrained scope, where it doesn't break referential transparency. This allows to layer pure and impure code without any interference. I would say that the best reasons to choose an impure approach are performance (but that should always be motivated by measurements -- and in most applications it's fair to say it wouldn't be economical to focus on this aspect) and allowing to express an algorithm in a way which is more direct and readable (which is a very good reason to choose an impure approach, as long as you get your abstractions right -- which is quite hard, but probably worth doing anyway).

To go into further depth, I think it's interesting to see at what the compiler outputs for these two methods: the Scala compiler is able to detect tail recursion and optimize it into what would result from a `while` loop, ensuring it's also stack-safe (you can also make sure that the compiler enforces that a function is tail-recursive with the [`@tailrec`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/3.4.0/scala/annotation/tailrec.html) annotation). I slightly tweaked your code to make the condition the same and here is the (cleaned) output of `javap -v` on the compiler output:

```
  public int imp(int);
    ...
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=3, args_size=2
         0: iload_1
         1: istore_2
         2: iload_2
         3: bipush        10
         5: if_icmpge     14
         8: iinc          2, 1
        11: goto          2
        14: iload_2
        15: ireturn
      ...

  public int tailRec(int);
    ...
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: iload_1
         1: bipush        10
         3: if_icmpge     12
         6: iinc          1, 1
         9: goto          0
        12: iload_1
        13: ireturn
      ...
```

Basically, the only difference that you can observe is the fact that in the recursive version you had to allocate a mutable variable (since it's Scala it's not possible to mutate an argument). And I wouldn't be surprised if on a warm JVM this is JIT'ed out of existence. ;-)